# MSAL iOS Quick Guide won't archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage, azure-ad-msal

I am a total xCode/Swift newbie coming from .NET world.  I have followed the steps laid out in the Call the Microsoft Graph API from an iOS app guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/guidedsetups/active-directory-ios) but am getting a build error: **Swift Compiler Error: No such module 'MSAL'** in ViewController.swift.  Re-checked everything yet still no solution.

Here is the ViewController class:

```swift
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ATCO MSAL Login Demo
//
//  Created by user128987 on 8/23/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 atco.com. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MSAL

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {

    let kClientID = "91600c46-........"
    let kAuthority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0"

    let kGraphURI = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/"
    let kScopes: [String] = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"]

    var accessToken = string()
    var applicationContext = MSALPublicClientApplication.init()

    @IBOutlet weak var loggingText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var signoutButton: UIButton!

    // This button will  invoke the call to the Microsoft Graph API. It uses the
    // built in Swift libraries to create a connection.

    @IBAction func callGraphButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        do {
            // We check to see if we have a current logged in user. If we don't, then we need to sign someone in.
            // We throw and interactionRequired so that we trigger the interactive sign in.

            if try self.applicationContext.users().isEmpty {
                throw NSError.init(domain: "MSALErrorDomain", code: MSALErrorCode.interactionRequired.rawValue, userInfo: nil)
            } else {

                // Acquire a token for an existing user silently

                try self.applicationContext.acquireTokenSilent(forScopes: self.kScopes, user: applicationContext.users().first) { (result, error) in

                    if error == nil {
                        self.accessToken = (result?.accessToken)!
                        self.loggingText.text = "Refreshing token sliently)"
                        self.loggingText.text = "Refreshed Access token is \(self.accessToken)"

                        self.singoutButton.isEnabled = true;
                        self.getContentWithToken()

                    } else {

                        self.loggingText.text = "Could not acquire token silently: \(error ?? "No error information" as! Error)"
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {

            // interactionRequired means we need to ask the user to sign-in.  This usually happens
            // when the user's Refresh Token is expired or if the user has changed their password
            // among other possibilities

            if error.code == MSALErrorCode.iteractionRequire.rawValue {

                self.applicationContext.acquireToken(forScopes: self.kScopes) { (result, error) in
                    if error == nil {
                        sel.accessToken = (result?.accessToken)!
                        self.loggingText.text = "Access token is \(self.accessToken)"
                        self.signoutButton.isEnabled = true;
                        self.getConetnWithToken()
                    } else {
                        self.loggingtext.text = "Could not acquire token: \(error ?? "No error information" as! Error)"
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {

            // This is the catch all error.

            self.loggingText.text = "Unable to acquire token. Got error: \(error)"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        do {
            // Inititalize a MSALPublicClinetApplication with a given clientID and authority
            self.applicationContext = try MSALPublicClinetApplication.init(clientId: kClientID, authority: kAuthority)
        } catch {
            self.loggingText.text = "Unable to create Appliocation context. Error \(error)"
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if self.accessToken.isEmpty {
            singoutButton.isEnabled = false;
        }
    }

    func getContentWithToken() {

        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default

        // Specify the Graph API endpoint
        let url = URL(string: kGraphURI)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        // Set the Authorization header for the request. We use Bearer tokens, so we specify Bearer + the token we got from the result
        request.setValue("Bearer \(self.accessToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

        urlSession.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                if result != nil {

                    self.loggingText.text = result.debugDescription
                }
            }.resume()
    }

    @IBAction func signoutButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        do {

            // Removes all tokens from the cache for this application for the provided user
            // first parameter:   The user to remove from the cache

            try self.applicationContext.remove(self.applicationContext.users().first)
            self.signoutButton.isEnabled = false;

        } catch let error {
            self.loggingText.text = "Received error signing user out: \(error)"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Additional background - I am running on MacInCloud (if it makes a difference).

I was finally able to build and run the code in the simulator by changing Input Files under Build Phases > Run Script from **$(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/MSAL.framework** to **/Users/user128987/Carthage/Build/iOS/MSAL.Framework**.

So my question is, how would the script **/usr/local/bin/carthage copy-frameworks** know to copy the framework to $(SRCROOT)/Carthage/Build/iOS/MSAL.Framework** and why does it not do it for me.

The above change allowed me to build and run the project in iOS simulator but it won't le me archive it after i change the **active scheme** to **Generic iOS Device**.  Why?

Comment: Have you tried to perform Product -> Clean, then build again? Also restarting XCode with reopening project can help.

Comment: Yes I did.  Cleaned a couple of times.  Restarted xCode.  Interestingly, the same import exists in AppDelegate.swift but no complaints about it.  Maybe it does not get to it until it compiles ViewController.swift.

Comment: Igor, can you show us your class?

Comment: Added ViewController class.

Comment: where did you add view controller, is in compile sources?

Comment: Can you please share with us how did you fix this issue?